# How do I visualize the 'phases' of these two waves in this example?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics, waves, interference

> [image]
>
> Fig 4.1 shows a displacement-distance graph for two electromagnetic waves A and B of the same frequency and amplitude. Wave A is travelling to the right and wave B is travelling to the left.
>
> The period of each wave is T. Determine the phase difference between the two waves
>
> 1. At the instant shown ( pi rad )
> 2. At the instant shown +1/8T
> 3. At the instant shown +3/8T

I can't get 2 and 3.
Attempt at a solution : T/8 seconds later means that wave A will 'travel' through a phase angle of pi/4 rad. But so will wave B. Some part of me says that since they are travelling in opposite directions, they will 'travel' through phase angles in the opposite directions i.e

[image]

But this is far too hand-wavey, and an immediate question which pops up is why does physically travelling in opposite directions imply that their phase changes oppositely as well? And lastly, does it matter if A moves clockwise and B moves anti-clockwise, or if B moves clockwise and A moves anti-clockwise? Since it's all relative, it shouldn't, but I'm not sure. A mathematical explanation would be great!

Comment: Your analysis seems fine in that if the time had been $+\frac T 4$ it is perhaps easier to visualise what the sum of the two waves is?

Comment: I can do it for +T/4 ( phase difference is 0 ) , but I want to learn the 'circle' method so that I can find the phase difference for any length of time after the instant shown, and I also want to do this in a somewhat rigorous way, perhaps using wave equations.

Comment: For Phase difference it shouldn't matter what wave you choose, since it's 'difference'. The difference of two numbers is non-negative, for example.

Comment: But then why do we 'move' the phases through opposite angles?